# cargar select dinamicamente a partir de otro select

Tags: jquery, ajax, phonegap, jquery-mobile

estoy trabajando con html, javascript, jquery, jquery mobile, base de datos mysql y tambien php.

Estoy tratando de llenar un select dinamicamente con ajax a partir de la seleccion de otro select.

aqui lleno el primer select (sin problemas)

```
    $("document").ready(function(e) {
```

$("#opt_modificar_jugador_equipo").load("../php/consultaDeEquipo.php");

```
   $("#opt_modificar_jugador_equipo").change(function(){
            id_equipo = $("#opt_modificar_jugador_equipo").val();
                    
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:"../php/consultaDeJugadorPorIdDeEquipo.php?id_equipo="+id_equipo,
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $.mobile.loading("show", {
                        text: "Verificando información...",
                        textVisible: true,
                        theme: "a",
                        textonly: false,
                        html: ""
                    });
                },
            success: function(result) {
                alert(id_equipo);
                estado = 1;
            
        },
        
            complete: function(result) {
            $.mobile.loading("hide");
            if(estado==1){
                $("#opt_modificar_nombre_jugador").load("../php/consultaDeJugadorPorIdDeEquipo.php?id_equipo="+id_equipo);
            
    
                }
            }
        
    });

   });
                        
    });
</script>
```

cuando intento llenar el 2do select (que es asi pero no se ve en la publicacion "se llama opt_modificar_nombre_jugador a partir del primero no hace nada...
(borre las direcciones exactas de las webs de los php)